# How to use core php into Codeigniter controller files?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to use http://demo.hazzardweb.net/imgPicker/docs/. I have downloaded all the files.

How can I convert it into a Codeigniter third party library or how can I call this class file in a Codeigniter controller? Is it possible to call the core php files directly in a controller to achieve this?

For example:

```
 require dirname(__FILE__) . '/ImgPicker.php';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new library for your project.

Your library classes should be placed within your `application/libraries` directory, as this is where CodeIgniter will look for them when they are initialized.

#### Be sure that:

- File names must be capitalized. For example: ImgPicker.php
- Class declarations must be capitalized. For example: class ImgPicker
- Class names and file names must match.

Your ImgPicker class file
Classes in general should have this basic prototype:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ImgPicker {

        // all stuff that your php library does
        public function some_method()
        {
            . . . 
        }
}
```

Then from your controller (or model) you can load your library with `$this->load->library('someclass');` and you can pass vars to the constructor dynamically like so:

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
$this->load->library('ImgPicker', $params);
```

You can find a lot of useful information how to create your own libraries (or convert existing php classes to CI libraries) at [CI documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html).